# Server.Transfer method for mobile version

Tags: seo, google-search-console, asp.net, responsive-webdesign

I just want to be sure if i use `server.transfer` **[method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800(v=vs.90).aspx)** for display `mobile` version of my website, is it good for `SEO` and `google` ? somehow i managed to use this method to display mobile version of my site.

Server detect mobile user agent by a function and use this method to change displaying page, with different content and design.

Now i'm wondering does google compare this (mobile) version with my desktop version? and what happen when it find out these are different?

My desktop version has `media` and is `responsive` but user can see new mobile design with this method, also google can *(i tested with fetch as google)*

I know `m.` sub domain is ok but what about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand `Server.Transfer` method is better than the old `Response.Redirect` method because its improve server request performance by reducing the number of requests. To me that is good enough and as long as the path parameter is clean you will always retrieve the necessary resources to load the page.

Responsive Design is Google recommended display method because the page URL and HTML stay the same. If your URL stays the same but the HTML changes google will classify this format as [Dynamic Serving](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/dynamic-serving), whereas if URL and HTML changes Google will treat it as [Separate URLs](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls).

Each format has a different approach when it comes to SEO. The way you identify the user-agent is also important for Dynamic Serving, Google Recommends using Vary HTTP. In the case of Separate URLs you need to establish the relationship between the URL-Version-1 and URL-Version-2, here Google recommends using the using the `<link>` tag, where the Desktop version needs `rel=”alternate”` and the mobile version needs `rel=”canonical”` to link Mobile and Desktop URLs.

Please take into account that if you are using *m.example.com* vs *example.com* they are essentially **different URLs**.

Whatever your approach might be the bottom line is that you need the following to be always true:

- Make sure the content and links on the mobile site are similar 90% to
  the desktop version.
- It is hightly recommended that the content is the same in both
  versions (Remember Google Prefers Responsive Websites where URL and
  content stays the same).
- Make sure to have structured markup for both the desktop and mobile
  version. Use the robots.txt testing tool to verify that your mobile
  version is accessible.
- Expandable content such as *Read More* will have more weight on mobile.
- Page speed of your mobile site will determine the rankings of your
  mobile site and desktop site.
- Google has started to use the mobile version of the web as their
  primary search engine index.

I highly recommend you to read [what Google have said about going Mobile First](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/11/mobile-first-indexing.html)

Comment: Thanks for explanation, So if i understand right, if i use Dynamic Serving, it is solve my problem?

Comment: @Mr.x in such case, make sure your server support Vary Headers. The Vary header tells the browser that the contents of the response will vary depending on the user agent that requests the page